# Pandas - String Concatenation with Array column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to make a new string from two columns in my dataframe. One of my columns contains 1 value. The other column contains an array. The end result should look like the third column below.

```
  Alpha  Val                Result
0   A    ['1, 2, 3']    ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']
```

I had tried list comprehension but it just returns an error "can only concatenate str (not "list") to str"

`[alpha + val for alpha in df['Alpha'].str.split(",") for val in df['Val'].str.split(",")]`

This kind of like a 1X1 matrix by a 1X3 matrix (but concatenating the strings) but I'm not sure how to achieve this using pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Alpha':['A', 'B'],
                  'Val':[['1, 2, 3'], ['4, 5, 6, 7']]})

def newlist(A,B):
    return [A + i.strip() for i in B[0].split(',')]

df['Result'] = df.apply(lambda x: newlist(x.Alpha, x.Val), axis=1)
```

Comment: if I wanted to skip NaN values for the Val column, how would I add in the condition? I tried adding an if statement but keep getting 'invalid syntax'

Comment: Can you show me an example of the data? Without looking at the data this is what I would suggest, drop the nans first and then apply the above function.

Answer (score 2):

using the data courtesy @challasandeep420 we can also do :

```
df['Result'] = (df['Val'].str[0].str.split(',').explode().str.strip()
                         .radd(df['Alpha']).groupby(level=0).agg(list))
print(df)

  Alpha           Val            Result
0     A     [1, 2, 3]      [A1, A2, A3]
1     B  [4, 5, 6, 7]  [B4, B5, B6, B7]
```